# How to add shadow to a group of CALayer using CATransform3D

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer, uibezierpath, cgpath

How can I add shadow to a group of CALayers?
I have a "FoldingView"-class which maintans several "SliceView"-classes. Each sliceview's layer will be givven a CATransform3D where I'm using the perspective property (.m34 = 1.0 / -1000).

How can I add a shadow with good visual logic? This is what I've been thinking so far:

1. I could get the path of each slice and combine these to get a shadow path.

   - I don't know how the get a path of CALayer when the layer is using CATransform3D
   - It might work visually, but I'm afraid it won't be totally right if the light is supposed to come from top left.
2. I could just apply standard CALayer shadow to all layers

   - It does not look good due to the shadow is overlapping each other

If anyone has any other suggestions or know how to code idea number 1 I'll be very happy! Here is a link to the sample project you see screenshot from.

[Download zipped application with code](http://shared.agens.no/public/hfossli/foldingview/no.agens.foldshadow.zip)

[image: Sample image from application]

Comment: Please add a comment if you are to downvote my question. I would like to know what's wrong with the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work as wanted. This is done per sliceview.

```
- (UIBezierPath *)shadowPath
{ 

    if(self.progress == 0 && self.position != VGFoldSliceCenter)
    {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];  
        return path;
    }
    else
    { 
        CGPoint topLeft = pointForAnchorPointInRect(CGPointMake(0, 0), self.bounds);
        CGPoint topRight = pointForAnchorPointInRect(CGPointMake(1, 0), self.bounds);
        CGPoint bottomLeft = pointForAnchorPointInRect(CGPointMake(0, 1), self.bounds);
        CGPoint bottomRight = pointForAnchorPointInRect(CGPointMake(1, 1), self.bounds);

        CGPoint topLeftTranslated = [self.superview convertPoint:topLeft fromView:self];
        CGPoint topRightTranslated = [self.superview convertPoint:topRight fromView:self];
        CGPoint bottomLeftTranslated = [self.superview convertPoint:bottomLeft fromView:self];
        CGPoint bottomRightTranslated = [self.superview convertPoint:bottomRight fromView:self];

        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

        [path moveToPoint:topLeftTranslated];
        [path addLineToPoint:topRightTranslated];
        [path addLineToPoint:bottomRightTranslated];
        [path addLineToPoint:bottomLeftTranslated];
        [path closePath]; 

        return path;
    } 
}
```